# How can i find summation of the series $i^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

Series :

$$\sum_{i =1}^{n} i^k= 1^k+ 2^k + 3^k + 4^k +\ldots+n^k$$

where $k$ is a constant.

This does not seem to be Geometric progression , how can I evaluate the sum?

If possible if also want to find

$$\sum_{j =1}^{n} F(j)$$

where $F(j)$ is sum of the above series at $n=j$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: No, it is not @jinawee .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) to see that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^k = \frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-1)^j\binom{k+1}{j}B_jn^{k+1-j}$$

where $B_j$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: see the edit , i also want to find its summation

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Well, you do the math. The formula is there.

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, look at the Bernoulli polynomials:
[sums of the pth powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Sums_of_pth_powers)